# Link from router refreshing whole page when it should not

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm having a small issue with React Router, when I am at my first Component called `WebsiteLoad` everything seems fine, but when I click on the `<Link />`it refreshes the whole page to load `/portfolio` when I just need it to render the respective Components specified to React-Router.

This is my code in `WebsiteLoad.js`:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import Hero from './Home/Hero'

class WebsiteLoad extends Component{
    render(){
      window.initDogma()
        return(
            <div id="wrapper">
  <div className="content-holder elem scale-bg2   no-padding">
    <div className="dynamic-title">Services</div>
    <div className="content full-height no-padding home-content ">
      <div className="full-height-wrap">
        <Hero />
        <div className="overlay" />
        <div className="enter-wrap-holder cent-holder wht-bg">
          <div className="enter-wrap">
            <h3>
              <img src="private_source" alt="Habitare logo" />
            </h3>
            <Link to="/portfolio" replace="false" className="ajax btn anim-button trans-btn transition ">
              <span>Todos los desarrollos</span>
              <i className="fa fa-long-arrow-right" />
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

        );
    }
}
export default WebsiteLoad;
```

And my `RouterConfig.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import WebsiteLoad from './WebsiteLoad'
import Portfolio from './Portfolio'

function RouteConfigExample() {
  return(
    <Router>
        <Route exact path="/" component={WebsiteLoad} />
        <Route path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
    </Router>
  )
}

export default RouteConfigExample;
```

And the code inside `Portfolio.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Header from './Header'
import SubNav from './SubNav'

class Portfolio extends Component{

    Project = (data = []) =>{
        return (
            <div key={data} className="gallery-item houses apartments">
                <div className="grid-item-holder">
                    <div className="box-item">
                    <div className="wh-info-box">
                        <div className="wh-info-box-inner at">
                        <a href="portfolio-single.html" className="ajax">
                            Modern house
                        </a>
                        <span className="folio-cat">Houses design</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="images/folio/thumbs/27.jpg" alt="Alt" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    loadProjects = () =>{
        var Projects = []
        for(var c=0;c<4;c++)
            Projects.push(this.Project(c))
        return Projects
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Header />
                <SubNav />
                <div id="wrapper">
  <div className="content-holder elem scale-bg2 transition3">
    <div className="content ">
      <section className="no-padding no-border">
        <div className="filter-holder filter-nvis-column">
          <div className="gallery-filters at">
            <button
              href="#"
              className="gallery-filter gallery-filter-active"
              data-filter="*"
            >
              All
            </button>
            <button
              href="#"
              className="gallery-filter "
              data-filter=".houses"
            >
              Houses
            </button>
            <button
              href="#"
              className="gallery-filter"
              data-filter=".interior"
            >
              Interior
            </button>
            <button
              href="#"
              className="gallery-filter"
              data-filter=".apartments"
            >
              Apartments
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="filter-button vis-fc">Filter</div>
        <div className="gallery-items   hid-port-info" >
            {this.loadProjects()}
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

        );
    }
}
export default Portfolio
```

How can I make React-Router to load the respective components keeping it "one-page website" instead of sending a whole new HTTP request?

## EDIT

I am adding a repo with the issue and a working environment so you can reproduce the issue. I'm still searching for the fix but no results.

Here is the repo: 
https://github.com/k3llydev/hi_website/tree/react-router-issue

Here is the app environment: https://hi-website.herokuapp.com

Comment: what are you using window.initDogma() for?

Comment: @vitomadio It's a call for an external JavaScript function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fix

When importing HTML templates in React, which is one of our labors to do when we work for someone else, you must make sure to:

> First understand the working environment around the template and its
>   JavaScript code.

I found the fix for the issue just by removing a simple `ajax` class on my elements to prevent the site reloading itself.

And then adding the template JavaScipt function calls inside my callback function in a `setState()` function. (When the document did load.)

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
        example: value
    },function(){
        window.initDogma()
    })
}
```

This fixed everything. Hope this helps someone else in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `Switch` from `react-roter-dom` in your code

Change your `RouterConfig.js` file as follows

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import WebsiteLoad from './WebsiteLoad'
import Portfolio from './Portfolio'

function RouteConfigExample() {
  return(
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={WebsiteLoad} />
        <Route path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
     </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default RouteConfigExample;
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't knew that Switch was required, also, where should I use it? Since it says it still unused in my developer console. Where should I use Switch?

Comment: Can you share relevant code from profile component?

Comment: I edited and added the code inside Portfolio.js @vitomadio

Comment: You have to wrap all the components in switch inside Router, Updated my answer please check @k3lly.dev

Comment: Can you create and share a minimal  reproducing repo

Comment: Haven't found the fix yet:(

Comment: @k3lly.dev  I have cloned your repo and checked but i its not reloading..What is your requrement

Comment: The issue is that since something is being reloaded, or called by AJAX, my portfolio is not loading. You can see what I mean with reloading /portfolio when you are at it. Also going back in browser history to the root directory.